# JavaScript (Ajax) + PHP - getting (and changing??) a link depending on PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am a beginner. I feel like I'm missing something in my thought process. I have tried a number of different things.

I'm coding a simple like button into each post of my site. I have three PHP functions related to this:

- `isLiked($id)` uses `$_Get['id']` for the post and the ip address of the
  user (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`) to check if the user has already liked
  that particular post.
- `likes()` inserts the "like" into the database -
  it also uses `$_GET['id']`
- `getLikes($id)` gets the number of likes for each `$id`

likePost.php is a simple page that just calls `likes()` (Inserts the like to the db) and echoes the result, which is `getLikes($id)`. Yes, I called the function within the function.

The JavaScript I'm working on looks like this (I am NOT promising this is good JS ).

```
function likeButton() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../likes/",  //This is likePost.php, after .htaccess rewrite
        type: "post",
        data: {
            id:id },
        success: function(likes) {
            somethingHereIDontKnowWhat(likes);  //UGH
        }});
}
```

and my link right now (sans JavaScript) + the number of likes now looks like this:

```
echo "<br/><div class='right'><a href='../../likes/" . $post->id . "'>
<img src='/images/like.png' title='Like this' alt='Like button'></a>" . getLikes($post->id) . "<div><br/>";
```

I can't wrap my head around using the JS to run the PHP function (while sending the $post_id to the url to make $_GET['id'], but also using the (same?) JS to print and update the number of likes when the link is pressed. That's at least two things the function is doing at the same time - or am I completely lost?

Which *should* get me the number of likes (cross your fingers!!), but I need a way to incorporate `isLiked()` into it, because the link should be *disabled* `if isLiked() = true`.

Comment: You just can't use PHP function on the back using ajax directly. To, make that happen, you have to respond to the request, then according to that response from back. You have to do things. Pardon me, if I did not understand what you want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I'm understanding correctly you want to update the number of likes once a post has been liked and then disable the like button?

First give your div an id, and get rid on the link.

```
echo "<br/><div class='right' id="post' . $post->id . '">
<img src='/images/like.png' title='Like this' alt='Like button' onClick="likeButton(' . $post->id . ')">" . getLikes($post->id) . "<div><br/>";
```

Then you can update the contents on the div from the ajax success. This will update the total and remove the like image.

```
function likeButton(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../likes/",  //This is likePost.php, after .htaccess rewrite
        type: "post",
        data: {
            id:id },
        success: function(likes) {
            $('#post' + id).html(likes);
        }});
}
```

Hopefully this was what you were asking for.

Also you shouldn't use the IP address to mark posts as liked. IP addresses can change, also multiple people can use the same IP. It would be better to set a cookie for each post the user has liked.

Comment: I won't be able to test this until later on, but it looks like what I was hoping for - as far as the IP address I'm aware of the problems, but it's a small site and I'm not expecting major spamming - I'm just trying (for now) to avoid cookies

Comment: I'm getting multiple syntax errors on the link code - seems like problems with the single/double quotes?

Comment: well, I got the link working using 
echo "<br/><div class='right' id='post' . $post->id . >
    <img src='/images/like.png' title='Like this' alt='Like button' onClick='likeButton(' . $post->id . ')'>" . getLikes($post->id) . "</div><br/>";

but now all link buttons are disabled - even the ones I haven't "liked"

Comment: It would only disable all the images if the ids are the same.

Comment: It's the result of isLiked($post->id) that should determine if the link is disabled or not - false should show the link active...

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood, what does 'likes' return?

Comment: No need to say sorry - you're being a HUGE help!
'likes' returns getLikes($_GET['id'] (the number of likes)
isLiked($post->id) returns boolean, has the IP "liked" this already or not

Comment: So in the success you can do if(likes) { $('#post' + id).html(''); }

Comment: I think we're ALMOST there - but shouldn't if(likes) be if(isLiked) or something like that? We haven't put that PHP function in the JS anywhere...

Comment: I think I'm still misunderstanding. The 'likes' variable returns the number of likes for a post? Also if the user has clicked on the like button, it would be liked right?

Comment: Right. "likes" returns the number of likes. "isLiked($post->id)" checks to see if the person (IP) has already liked it or not. If they have, the link should be disabled so they don't do it again

Comment: Oh, you just need to do that on page load use if(!isLiked($post->id)) {} to echo the image

Comment: Yeah that's what I've done - but then the whole page needs to be reloaded before the link will become disabled, right?? And with the current js, all the links are disabled to start with, so...

Comment: You don't need to reload the page, thats what the ajax call is for. likeButton() should only fire when you click on the like image, then it updates the page.

Comment: @ok awesome - but why are all links disabled right now?

Comment: They shouldn't be, if you post your code I can take a look.

Comment: too much for comments, but you can see the code here: https://controlc.com/afae5879

Comment: There were ome errors with the quotes, hopefully this will fix it https://controlc.com/c8fbcb34